# show that $T:V \to V $, where $V$ is finite dimensional with $(T-aI)(T-bI)=0, a \neq b $ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have shown that the possible eigenvalues for $T$ are $\lambda_1 = a$ and $\lambda_2 = b$.
Now,I want to show that $V = E_{\lambda_1} \bigoplus E_{\lambda_2}$ to conclude that $T$ is diagonalizable. I am stuck at this point as I cannot find a way to express $v$ as the sum of two vectors in each eigenspace. Any hints?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since you ask for hints:  First prove this when $a=0$ and $b=1$, i.e. $T$ is idempotent -- there are many proofs of diagonalizability of idempotent matrices on this site.  Then  recover the general case from this special case.

Comment: Please use \to, not \mapsto, in this context. If you define a function by saying $x\mapsto f(x)$ for an element $x$ of the domain, then that is an appropriate use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general theorem that says $T$ is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial has no repeated root. But to follow your path, you want to find vectors $w_1, w_2$ such that $$\begin{cases} w_1+w_2=v \\ aw_1+bw_2=T(v)\end{cases}$$

The second equation is the result of applying $T$ to the first one.
After you find $w_1, w_2$, you can check that $Tw_1=aw_1$ and $Tw_2=bw_2$ hold, using the fact that $(T-a)(T-b)=0$ hence $T^2(v)=aT(v)+bT(v)-ab(v)$.

This argument doesn't depend on $\dim(V)<\infty$.

Comment: Many books don't introduce the minimal polynomial this early in the teaching of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Also, diagonalizability is only defined for operators on finite dimensional vector spaces. The definition of diagonalizability is that there exists a basis of the underlying vector space with respect to which the operator $T$ has a diagonal matrix.

Comment: There is absolutely no difficulty in generalizing the definition to arbitrary vector spaces: There exists a basis consisting of only eigenvectors of $T$. Although this is not the "right" one when self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces are considered. Mathematics is not at all about definitions made only on textbooks etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about the Jordan decomposition then you can note that the minimal polynomial divides $(x-a)(x-b)$ and go on from there.